# Form html and sender php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a form on html page that sends 2 emails. here the html code:

```
<form class="pix-form-style pixfort-form pix-padding-top-20 pix-form-light-white-bg" action="invio_mail.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="Nome">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Cognome">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" placeholder="Città">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Numero telefono">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn yellow-bg small-text btn-lg pix-white btn-block"><span class="pix_edit_text"><strong>Richiedi informazioni</strong></span></button>
    <div class="form-group" style="color:white; display: flex;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="policies" value="" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 5px;height:auto !important;" required><p>Dichiaro di aver letto ed accettato l'informativa</p>
    </div>
</form>
```

here the php

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = "my-email@webmail.com"; // email azienda
$from = $_POST['email']; // email cliente

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$policies= $_POST['policies'];

$subject = "Richiesta Informazioni";
$subject2 = "Copia Richiesta Informazioni";

$message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " " . $email . " " . $phone . " " . $city . " " . $policies;
$message2 = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " " . $email . " " . $phone . " " . $city . " " . $policies;

$headers = "From:" . $from;
$headers2 = "From:" . $to;

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); 

echo "Richiesta Inviata! " . $first_name . ", ti contatteremo al più presto.";
}?>
```

I get

> 405 error - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
> The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.

Comment: If you get `404` it means the address of the page is wrong. Please check that the file name are the same and the paths are the same. From your code  `invio_mail.php` should be in the same directory as the HTML. Is this the case?

If you get `403` you need to check your server logs to better understand

Comment: Why are you using that `<script src...`? `if(isset($_POST['submit'])` There is no element with that `name` attribute! There's also no element with `name="name"` (`$_POST['name']`)!

Comment: thanks for the answer, yes I checked the file name and path, they are correct.
yes, the php and the html are in the same directory.
I get 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.

check the server log error

Comment: i am not familiar with php, i did research and tried to adapt them to my needs. already give me a starting point for corrections, thanks

Comment: Why are you including php file with script tag
<script src="https://www.site-path.com/test/sender_mail/invio_mail.php"></script>

Comment: @Mohammad Fahad Rao
ok, so i dont need to include php via script tag, that it s probabli incorrect, can i call the php function through the form action ?

Comment: @brombeer 
i ve change $first_name = $_POST['name']; into $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; as in html, thx for ur comment

Comment: but why are you calling function
As i understand you are trying to send data,right?
and $_POST['policies'] value is not in form

Comment: No need to include the `<script src...`, you can savely remove it. The `action` attribute will handle the submission to the file. But unless you give your submit button a `name="submit"` attribute that script will do nothing

Comment: @Mohammad Fahad Rao
yes, I would like an email to be sent with the data entered in the form, sorry I'm a beginner of php.

Comment: @brombeer 
ok I inserted the tag, and I added name = "submit" to the submit button. thanks for the note. i get error
405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.

Comment: 405 is usually what the web server responds with, when it thinks what you tried to POST to was a “static” file, and not a script. Since your form action is already pointing to a `.php` file here, the next question would by - is your server configured to get those parsed as PHP to begin with?

Comment: @CBroe unfortunately the server is in the hands of third parties. I have already asked for this info and are waiting for an answer.
I wanted to understand if php and html were fine. and thanks to the community I have already made some changes.